# Populate @html.DropDownListFor() with items in Twitter Bootstrap style and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2012, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to populate a drop down list of items. I am using MVC4 with the twitter bootstrap styling, on visual studio 2012.

The code that I have for the controller is:

```
String[] genders =  { "Male","Female","Other"};
ViewBag.genders = new SelectList(genders);
```

And in my view is:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor("genders", "Select a gender", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

However, I get an error:

> 'The type arguments for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   object)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type
>   arguments explicitly.'

I have tried various other forms of the statement. But basically I would like to keep the controller as is and edit the statements in the view. But I am open to anything which people are willing to suggest that will help me solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedGender, (SelectList)ViewBag.genders, "Select gender", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

`m=>m.SelectedGender`, is where you bind the value to something in your view's model (or if you have no model, you should use `@Html.DropDownList` supplying a string instead).

Comment: Thank you for your help but still have some error:
System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Tutorial.Models.Profile>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.
How can one cast the arguements?

Comment: Try casting ViewBag.genders as a SelectList: `(SelectList)ViewBag.genders`

Comment: @Gman16 Great! I updated my answer with the cast. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.DropDownListFor` expect a lamda expression, not a string as it first parameter.

Now... to use a `DropDownListFor`... you need a Model in your view. That model should have a Property where you will store the selected value when you post the form where the DDL is in.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Gender, (SelectList)ViewBag.genders, "Select gender", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Now, if you don't have a model in your view... you should use `@Html.DropDownList()`
In this case, you can just enter a name as a first parameter.

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedGender", (SelectList)ViewBag.genders, "Select gender", new { @class = "form-control" })
```